# 90's/00's Audio book series post apocalyptic where they use gates to travel

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic, audio-book

An audio book series sold at truck stops with over 18 titles from late 1990s/early 2000s post apocalyptic where they use gates to travel, possibly brilliance audio. It's science fiction/technology. In the stories the apocalypse occurred in 2000/2001.  The story is set 100 years later. All of the characters are adults and the gates were created by the government.  The name was along the genre of badlands, wastelands, etc.

Comment: I hope you can provide us with some more details. You can find some prompts at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info to help you ferret out more. Were these magic gates? Science Fiction technology? Mundane gates that just were how you got on the road? Were the protagonists adults? Children? Aliens?

Comment: This matches multiple stories put out by Brilliance. Probably it's [Gate of Ivrel](https://www.brillianceaudio.com/product?i=22521) but could just as easily be [The Crippled God](https://www.brillianceaudio.com/product?i=6835) or a dozen others. Gates as portals is a common fantasy trope.

Comment: Ah, but is _Gate of Ivrel_ fantasy or science fiction? :)

Comment: @DavidW - It's pretty close to fantasy, with some pretentions of science-fantasy.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Its driving me nuts. I'm looking for something to listen to on the way to work. I have listened to this series before and I know it will give me a lot of hours.

Comment: I found it! Its Deathlands by Graphic audio. I spent a whole day googling it and nothing. I googled again today and found it. Thanks for everyone's help.